# Fix $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime. Is every sequence $(a_i) \in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\sum a_i p^{-i} = 1$ ultimately periodic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Fix $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime and consider a sequence of integers $(a_i)$. I would like to show that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{p^i} = 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (a_i) \text{ ultimately periodic}  \tag{1}
$$
which may or may not be true. The only such sequences I can think of are the constant sequence $(p-1)$ and the sequences $(a_i)$ such that
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{p^i} = \overbrace{\frac{1}{p^n} + \dotsb + \frac{1}{p^n}}^{p^n \text{ times}}
$$
For example, consider the sequence defined as
$$
\begin{cases}
a_i = p^{i-1} & \text{for } 1 \leq i \leq p \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I would be done if I could prove that these cover all the possible cases, but are they?

---

**Edit:** Thomas Andrews provided a nice counterexample with $a_i$ unbounded. Can we recover (1) with the extra assumption that the terms of $(a_i)$ are chosen in a finite subset of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a sequence of the second kind $: (a^{(n)}_i)?$ I don't quite understand exactly what sequences are they.

Comment: The others are variations on the example, with only $p^n$ non-zero terms $a_i = p^{i - n}$.

Comment: In response to the edit question: if you force the $a_i$ to be between $0$ and $p-1$ (inclusive) this is just a familiar property of base $p$ expansion (the right hand side being replace-able by any rational number). Or do you mean an arbitrary finite subset?

Comment: @hunter: Indeed, I was fiddling with the property you mention to see if there was any room for a more general statement, with the ultimate goal of an analogous property for the $\beta$ expansion of an algebraic number in $(0,1)$ with $\beta > 1$ a real algebraic integer.

Comment: I've answered it in the negative with $a_i$ chosen from $\{0,p-1,p^2-1\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_{n^2}=p^{2n-1}-1$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise.

This amounts to gathering terms for your original series:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{p-1}{p^i}$$

It starts like (ignoring the zero terms):

$$ \frac{p-1}{p} + \frac{p^3-1}{p^4} + \frac{p^5-1}{p^9}+\cdots$$

More generally, there are uncountably many such sequences $a_n$, and there are only countably many $(a_i)$ that eventually repeat.

The finite terms case also is not true.

If the $a_i$, for example, must be picked from $\{0,p-1,p^2-1\}$, then let $S$ be any subset of the natural numbers.

If $n\in S$ define $a_{2n-1} = 0$ and $a_{2n}=p^2-1$.

If $n\notin S$ define $a_{2n-1}=a_{2n}=p-1$.

Then this gives uncountably many sequences $(a_n)$, and since the number of eventually repeating sequences is countable.

Comment: What if I assume the $a_i$ chosen in a finite set?

Comment: No idea about the finite set version of the question.

Comment: BTW, I think you mean to say $a_{n^2}=p^{2n-1}.$

Comment: @awllower No, it's definititely $p^{2n-1}-1$. $$\frac{p^3-1}{p^4}=\frac{p-1}{p^2}+\frac{p-1}{p^3}+\frac{p-1}{p^4}$$

Comment: If $a_n=p^{2n-1}-1$ then $a_4=p^7-1,$ so $a_4/p^4=(p^7-1)/p^4.$

Comment: No, if $a_n=p^{2n-1}$ then $a_4=p^{7}$. @awllower

Comment: Ah, what I mean is $a_{n^2} = p^{2n-1}-1$. @awllower

Comment: No, you didn't @awllower You wrote namy things that were just as wrong. For example, $a_{n^2}=p^{2n-1}$ is wrong.

Comment: OK, sorry about the first typo: $p^{2n-1},$ but I meant to remind you of the index $a_{n^2}.$ Apology here.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the changed subscript because I thought you were correcting by removing the $-1$. @awllower

Comment: @AP I've added the answer for finite sets, and the answer is still no.